# How do I get an MS Access form to read a variable from another form's code?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that is running code to request the user audit a warehouse location. After the user gives all the part numbers in that location, the code stops and opens another form as acDialog so the user can verify that all the entries are correct. There are two buttons on the second form; one closes the form and continues the code from the first form, but I want the other button to restart the first form so the user can re-enter the part numbers if necessary. How do I get these forms to share a variable?

I've tried to make the variable Public on the original form, but the other form doesn't see it or can't alter it. I could hack it together and just have the original form create a simple table and have the second form alter it, but I feel like there's a better way to get around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public variables declared in a form module are only available to the functions and subroutines in that specific form. You need to declare your public variable in a code module. This will make it visible in all form modules and code modules.

Create a module - basMain for example

Module code:

```
Option Explicit

Public MyVariable as YourRequiredType
```

Comment: It's not true though. Public variables in forms are available to all functions/subroutines, as long as they're used as properties of that form. Depending on how you refer to the form, intellisense may not know they are available, but they certainly are. Else, there would be no difference between private and public variables in form modules.

Comment: @ErikA, Agreed however I personally tend to avoid using form variables in a global context and lean more towards the use of a global class to manage these types of interactions between objects.